# Insert the data of multiple tabs created by user in MYSQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, tabs

I am trying to insert the data of text area of tabs in MYSQL using PHP. I am able to insert the data of only predefined tab but I am not able to insert the data of newly created tabs when user clicks on *ADD TAB* button and create his own tab.

Any ideas how it can be done?

here is my HTML output: http://jsfiddle.net/HMv9S/1/

I have tried this MySQL code for inserting the data and successfully can insert the data of predefined tab:

```
<?php
   if ($_POST['submit'])
    {
      $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","my_db");
      $texts=array($_POST['txt']);
      foreach($texts as $value)
      {
          $allTextArea = implode(",", $value);
          $text = mysql_real_escape_string($allTextArea); 
          $query= "INSERT INTO Sections(data) VALUES('$text')";
          mysqli_query($con,$query);
      }

    }
?>
```

Comment: easy way: use `array` to store post data, in your case change `<textarea name="txt"></textarea>` name attr to `name="txt[]"` then on php side You can use `foreach` to insert data

Comment: @waldek_c can you please help me with the snippet,bcoz I am getting entire result in a same row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should name the textarea as an array like `txt[]` instead of txt. Now on form submit you will get all the textarea values.

```
if ($_POST['submit']){
$allTextArea = $_POST['txt'];
print_r($allTextArea);
}
```

Comment: Thanx for the answer. It works fine. I am able to store the newly created tab contents _but now I am not getting predefined tab contents with this_.

Comment: predefined tab contents?

Comment: you can say like which I have already defined earlier for user..like in my fiddle _about us_

Comment: you have to change its name also to txt[]

Answer (score 0):

Input elements attribute name must be unique (semantically also id). Then iterate through possible keys received in `$_POST`.

In single form you are creating multiple input elements (in your case `<textarea>`) with same `name` attribute. in `$_POST`, values are sent in format `'key' => value` with input element attribute name as key. All your textareas has `'txt'` as name.